# How to restrict the presence of the Keyboard/Keypad

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity with a layout that contains an `EditText` and a `ListView`. Initially, when the activity starts, the `KeyBoard` appears. But I want the `KeyBoard to appear only if the user touched the`EditText` Area to write some text,and to dismiss otherwise. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this issue pops up a lot with lots of ways to fix it. I solved this a variety of ways. The easiest was to put the following attribute in my parent layout (LinearLayout in my case):

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:bla bla bla other stuff
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've also tried various things like setting the following attributes in the Activity tag in my AndroidManifest.xml (sometimes this works, but I think it depends on your API level):

```
 <activity
            android:name="some.awesome.activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And have even done it programmatically (and painfully) like this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(someEditText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(someEditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hopefully one of these helps!

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior for the keyboard.  If its appearing immediately, you have to have something in the xml or your code that's focusing an edit text.

Comment: can you please provide an example? or tell me which property of the EditTest can do this task